# Can't set PolygonShape vertices Box2D

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, polygon

I'm using Box2D in Java with LIBGDX. I'm trying to create a triangle using `PolygonShape`. Upon calling `setVertices` my code crashes.  There is no error code, or stack trace for me to follow.

Excuse the lengthy numbers. They are the exact numbers being calculated. The routine is more complicated than this, but this is all that's needed to solve the problem here.

```
PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
//app crashes on call to set.
shape.set(new float[] { 0.26666668f, -0.043010756f, -0.008602151f,
    -0.18064517f, -0.18064517f, -0.26666668f });
```

I've ensured my vertices are in counter-clockwise order. These points define a simple convex triangle.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calculate the slope between the points given, you'll all are within `.5` with very little difference. I think Box2D was complaining because the points were all lying on approximately the same line.

I also noticed this was quite a small polygon. I fixed the problem by discarding polygons that were too small. I haven't ran into another polygon like this since then.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it crashes in the native code portion. Any chance you [upgraded to a newer version of gdx](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1019) by replacing the libgdx jar's but not replacing the libgdx.so?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I expect that's why I'm getting no error. Usually I'll get some kind of printout though. No, I haven't upgraded ever. Not sure what version I'm using. Tried to check that, and can't find any version numbers on anything. Whatever the most recent version was 4-6 months ago.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for the help. I'm going to post solution and accept tomorrow.

Comment: Cheers, curious to know what it turned out to be then!